# Strange CoreData error ... value returned from insertNewObjectForEntityForName: appears to be corrupt

Tags: ios

I have a very strange error happening in an App that has been working for a long time.

I can no longer create one of my entities in my CoreData model.

When I create one particular entity in my model and try to print it using NSLog( @"%@", obj ), I get this strange message:

2011-11-08 13:03:05.936 iLearnFast[31541:15503] -[__NSCFNumber objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa069e20

When I loop over the attributes / relationships for this object and print them out, one particular one to one relationship returns a strange value from [obj valueForKey:]. The value it returns is the same pointer / object that is mentioned in the above error message.

I thought I might have been corrupting memory somewhere, but I inserted the code to create the entity at the very beginning of my executable as soon as datastructures are initialized, and I get the same problem. I am extremely confident that I have not made any memory errors at this point (and a memory error would be more random ... I can create thousands of objects, and always the same entity has the same problem with the same relationship, and no other entities ever have a problem).

After narrowing down the problem to this one relationship, I found that I could make the error go away by renaming the relationship to anything else. The relationship has been called "file" since my App was created.

I can make my code work again by renaming the property, although it messes up my automatic lightweight migration, but now I have to deal with figuring out how to do a more complicated migration.

If anyone has any ideas as to what might be going wrong, I would really appreciate it.

This is baffling me, and really feels like a bug in Apple's SDK.

I'm currently using XCode 4.2 and tried both the SDKs for both iOS5.0 and iOS4.3 and both had the same behaviour.

Ron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2011-11-08 13:03:05.936 iLearnFast[31541:15503] -[__NSCFNumber
>   objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa069e20

I guess you have a leak in your code. This line means that you trying to access `objectID` property which contains in your custom NSManagedObject, but for some reason that object no longer lives. Try to check your code on memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So my object somehow has a corrupt objectID? I put this code at the VERY beginning when my App has done nothing except for creating the managed object model / managed object context. Also ... how could a leak be causing the problem? I thought I might be randomly stomping on memory somewhere, but this error happens instantly right after the call to create the object.

Comment: I also tried changing my object to not be a custom object, but instead be a NSManagedObject directly. Same problem. When I create the NSManagedObject, the one particular relationship is corrupt with a bogus objectID.

Comment: Maybe when you save context, coredata trying to save all your objects, and you received this error?

Comment: Again ... thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I get the error without saving the context. My application just starts up, loads the ManagedObjectModel, creates a PersistentStoreContext and a ManagedObjectContext, and then tries to create my "problem" entity. I stop in the debugger immediately after the object is created and print it out, and it is already corrupt. Renaming the problem relationship to anything else causes my App to work perfectly.

Comment: Solved!!! My "problem" relationship was "file", and I had extended NSObject to have an "isFile" method that I used to test my objects. Somehow, this must have been colliding with some automatically generated CoreData methods. It was kind of an ugly way of doing what I wanted to do, so I'll re-think.

Comment: This helps a lot, it looks like it's very simple to interference with dynamically generated core data methods. I'm starting using object accessors or services only :-)

Comment: Nice one @Ron, I was going mental

Answer (score 4):

I saw this same issue arise in a Swift project using Core Data. The issue only raised it's head when I pushed the app onto a device (it had been working fine in the simulator for some time).

The issue centred around a relationship between two entities. To illustrate see problem image:

[image: Problem]

After looking around SO for sometime I decided to rename the relationships, **captain** and **player**. See fix image:

[image: Fix]

Only after renaming both 'ends' of the relationship did the error go away.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I had same error message and in my case reason was that I had relation property `teacher` and created read-only property `isTeacher`.

This issue caused by Objective-C name conventions: CoreData was confused in getting `teacher` property. Instead of accessing real relation and giving me real object it taking `isTeacher` getter with `BOOL` type, cast it to `NSNumber` and try to deal with it like CoreData relation and call `objectID`.

After renaming `isTeacher` to `isTeacherLicence` problem gone.

Comment: I had the same issue, a relation property called competitor, and a computed property called isCompetitor. Renaming isCompetitor to isCompetitorDisplay solved the issue. Thanks!